# Ordenar indice de tipo datetime

Tags: pandas, datetime

tengo un dateframe cuyos indices son valores de tipo datetime. Lo único que estan en formato '%d of %B', es decir por ejemplo :  5 of May.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna manera de ordenar los indices de menor a mayor. Al ejecutar:

```
df.sort_index()
```

se me ordenan como si fuera un string es decir, primero mira el número después la primera letra del mes, etc, en vez de cronologicamente, por ejemplo:

```
01 of April
01 of August
01 of June
...
```

Se me ocurre pasarlo a formato '%m:%d', para que así me ordene númericamente primero el mes y después el dia. Pero me gustaría saber si hay alguna función que desconozco para ordenar el indice sin tener que hace este paso intermedio, ya que al ser el indice de tipo datetime supongo que esta funcionalidad debería de existir.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que el `DataFrame` tiene un índice que ha dejado de ser un `datetime` para ser una solamente una cadena. Por ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd

df =  pd.DataFrame({
  "fecha": pd.to_datetime(['2019-04-01', '2019-01-11', '2019-01-09']),
  "valor": [1, 2, 3]
  }
)
df = df.set_index('fecha', drop=False)
print(df.index)

> # Es un índice datetime
> DatetimeIndex(['2019-04-01', '2019-01-11', '2019-01-09'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='fecha', freq=None)

df.index = df.index.strftime('%d of %B')
print(df.index)

> # Ahora el índice ha dejado de ser un datetime
> Index(['01 of April', '11 of January', '09 of January'], dtype='object')
```

De modo que no podrás usar `df.sort_index()` al menos, de la forma en que estás esperando que funcione (orden por fecha). Si conservas la fecha como columna en el `dataframe` podrías:

#### Ordenar por la columna:

```
df.sort_values('fecha', inplace=True) # o df = df.sort_values('fecha')
print(df)

09 of January 2019-01-09      3
11 of January 2019-01-11      2
01 of April   2019-04-01      1
```

#### Regenerar y luego ordenar por índice:

```
df = df.set_index('fecha', drop=False)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(df)

fecha  valor
fecha
2019-01-09 2019-01-09      3
2019-01-11 2019-01-11      2
2019-04-01 2019-04-01      1
```

Si no dispones de la columna original, estás en problemas. Eventualmente podrías hacer alguna función que transforme los nombres de los meses en número, pero siempre estarías complicado si hay más de un años en la serie de datos.